# Drupal : Modify node - hook_node_insert / hook_node_insert

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, nodes

I have a problem with Drupal 7, I have a content type named "server", wich contains different fields :

- hostname
- CPU speed
- ...

The field hostname is entered manually. The others field must be entered progamatically.
So I specified a hostname and a function must search the information (CPU speed, ...) and fills the empty fields.

But I don't manage to update my node. I tried the functions `hook_node_insert` and  `hook_node_insert`. When I print the node before (1) and after (2) the use of theses functions I can see the difference. But when I access the node `http://localhost/drupal/?q=node/32` modifications have disappeared.

Here is a part of my function :

```
function module_node_presave($node) {
    if ($node->type == 'server') {

        dpm($node); //(1)
        $node->field_server_cpu_speed[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']  = 55;
        dpm($node); //(2)

    }
}
```

Can someone help me ?

Thanks in advance,
BDR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the [Computed field](https://drupal.org/project/computed_field) module to create the dynamic fields or add the `node_save($node);` at the end of the codes to save the node:

```
function module_node_presave($node) {
  if ($node->type == 'server') {
    $node->field_server_cpu_speed[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']  = 55;
    node_save($node);
  }
}
```

Comment: This made an infinite loop for me with error: `( ! ) Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached,`

Comment: That may be true since it is a _presave() hook. You could add a ```drupal_exit();``` at the end of the function.